# Access class item generated from xml using xsd.exe

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

Well, I generated some classes to deal with some xml files using the .net xsd.exe, no problem so far. I can read and deserealize the classes with the XmlSerializaer, and read most of the itens without any issue.

My issue is when I arrive at some places like the one bellow:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe")]
public partial class TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPIS
{

    private object itemField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PISAliq", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISAliq))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PISNT", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISNT))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PISOutr", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISOutr))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PISQtde", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISQtde))]
    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I can access the public object "Item", but how can I go deeper?
And when I get at ...Pis I can only access "Item".

One of the elements from the item above:

```
 /// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe")]
public partial class TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISAliq
{

    private TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISAliqCST cSTField;

    private string vBCField;

    private string pPISField;

    private string vPISField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISAliqCST CST
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cSTField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.cSTField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string vBC
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vBCField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.vBCField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string pPIS
    {
        get
        {
            return this.pPISField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.pPISField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string vPIS
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vPISField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.vPISField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I would need to access the public string vBC, pPis and others inside the TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISAliq class.

Here is a piece of the XML used to generate the classes (just removed the documentation to save space):

```
<xs:element minOccurs = "0" name="PIS">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>whatever</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name = "PISAliq" >
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>whatever;</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name = "CST" >
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>whatever;</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:whiteSpace value = "preserve" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value = "01" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value = "02" />
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name = "vBC" type="TDec_1302">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>whatever</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:element>
```

Comment: Please show us how the corresponding types are defined is the XSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have an `Item` property of type `object`, which will be deserialized to either a `TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISAliq` or any of the other three types marked with the `[XmlElement("PIS...", typeof(...)]` types.

Then you need to determine its type at runtime:

```
var deserializedObjectAliq = deserialized.Item as TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISAliq;
if (deserializedObjectAliq != null)
{
    deserializedObjectAliq.WhatEver
}

var deserializedObjectNT = deserialized.Item as TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISNT;
if (deserializedObjectNT != null)
{
    deserializedObjectNT.WhatEver
}

// ...
```

You'd better generate a member per `<xsd:choice>` rather than storing it in an `object`, so you can just check `if (deserializedObject.Aliq != null) { ... }`.

I'm not sure whether you can tell `xsd.exe` to generate those members instead. If it doesn't, you can create a partial class that does this:

```
public partial class TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPIS
{
    public TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISAliq Aliq
    {
        get
        {
            return Item as TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISAliq;
        }
    }       

    public TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISNT NT
    {
        get
        {
            return Item as TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISNT;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

See also [Dilemma with XSD, Generics and C# Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574822/dilemma-with-xsd-generics-and-c-sharp-classes) and [XSD.exe - How to initialize a type created from xs:choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278507/xsd-exe-how-to-initialize-a-type-created-from-xschoice).

Comment: tks, best way for me too, just needed to use a lot of for each loops.